# French V-to-T movement and modifier

Tags: syntax, historical-linguistics, syntax-trees, french

[image]

I am struggling with this question that concerns the location of a modifier in a French sentence. How would you account for the last sentence?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your translations into English are weird. e.g. *Pierre veut souvent manger des pommes* is "Pierre often wants to eat apples".  What do you mean with *of.the"? *Des* is either "some" or zero article. Your question is about adverb placement in French and would probably be better on  be better on [French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour). Adverbs are usually placed immediately after the conjugated verb, so the general rule applies here, but we might find exceptions. And even in your example sentence the place could vary for special effect.

Comment: It seems your questions contains a copy (image) from a printed matter and the wording isn't yours. So please state where it comes form and who wrote it.

Comment: @None As is common on linguistics courses, the OP's been given a variety of data from different languages. The idea is that you don't need to know the language concerned to be able to account for the data. This is the perfect site for such questions.

Comment: So, this is the perfect site for students to get us to do their homework?

Comment: @None, the lines containing “of.the” are glosses, not translations; they are meant only to show that a word literally meaning “of the” is in there.

Comment: What do V and T mean here?